Is it possible to track changes in formulas with script apps?
I am trying to create a code that will track changes made in spreadsheet and log those changes into a separate sheet.
The code itself works well but only with checking the values, so I am having a problem with checking the changes within formulas. I trying to find a solution but I guess that onEdit() function is not able to check changes made to formula, because I am getting only formula after change.
What I mean is I want to get a change in formula when someone will change it manually. Let's say in a cell I have =SUM(A2:A) and someone will change it to =SUM(B2:B). I hope that it is a good explanation to what I am trying to achieve.
Does someone know if there is any workaround for this problem?
function chnageHistory(e) {

  // Get the range that was edited
  var range = e.range;

  // Get the sheet that was edited
  var sheet = range.getSheet();

  // Get the name of the edited sheet
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // Get the current date and time
  var timestamp = new Date();

  // Get the user who made the edit
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Get the edited range address
  var rangeAddress = range.getA1Notation();

  // Get the old value before the edit
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;

  // Get the new value after the edit
  var newValue = e.value;

  // Get the old formula before the edit
  var oldFormula = range.getFormula();

  // If the formula is changed, log it
  if (e.oldFormula !== undefined && e.oldFormula !== oldFormula) {
    var newFormula = oldFormula;
    oldFormula = e.oldFormula;
    newValue = range.getValue(); // Get the new value from the cell since formula changed
  }

  // Add a single quote in front of the formula
  var formattedOldFormula = "'" + oldFormula;
  var formattedNewFormula = "'" + newFormula;

  // Log the edit details to a separate sheet
  var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LogBook");
  logSheet.appendRow([timestamp, user, sheetName, rangeAddress, oldValue, newValue, formattedOldFormula]);
}


There is no e.oldFormula field, and no turnkey way to track formula edits. You could save a copy of formula texts in a hidden helper sheet to find whether a formula was edited, or alternatively use the Drive API and the Revisions resource. See Download and publish file revisions and How to get older versions of Google Spreadsheet data for sample code.

Perhaps this can be done by logging existing formulas the first time a formula is entered or modified, and recording the previous formula by referring to the previous formula recorded in the log.
Try the code below. Note that it tracks changes by looking at row and column labels in the frozen section of the sheet, and if there is no frozen section, by looking at row 1 and column A. The labels in those frozen cells should be unique.
Also note that the code cannot "look back". It will only record changes from the time when you added the code in your script project.
'use strict';

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.');
  logFormulaChanges_(e);
}


/**
* Logs changes to formulas.
* Only writes to the log when a formula is entered in a sheetsToWatch.
* Will not log when a formula is deleted.
* Expects that the sheet has a frozen row and a frozen column, and that
* that those cells contain unique row and column labels.
* Uses row and column labels to identify cells instead of relying on
* cell addresses, to guard against row and column inserts.
* Defaults to row 1 and column A when there are no frozen rows or columns.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function logFormulaChanges_(e) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 5 August 2024
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78558527/13045193
  if (e.value && !e.value.match(/^=/i)) return;
  try {
    const parameters = [

      ////////////////////////////////
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        sheetsToWatch: /./i,
        sheetsToExclude: /^(Formula change log)$/i,
        logSheetName: 'Formula change log',
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]
      ////////////////////////////////

    ];
    let sheet, sheetName;
    const settings = parameters.find(p =>
      (sheetName = sheetName || (sheet = sheet || e.range.getSheet()).getName()).match(p.sheetsToWatch)
      && (!p.sheetsToExclude || !sheetName.match(p.sheetsToExclude))
    );
    if (!settings) return;
    let logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(settings.logSheetName);
    if (!logSheet) {
      logSheet = e.source.insertSheet(settings.logSheetName);
      logSheet.appendRow(['Timestamp', 'Sheet', 'Cell address', 'Row label', 'Column label', 'New formula', 'Old formula', 'New value', 'Old value',]);
      logSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
      logSheet.getRange('A2:A').setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss');
      settings.logSheetAdded = true;
    }
    const existingLogs = logSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().slice(1).filter(row => row[0]);
    const previousLogEntry_ = (rowLabel, columnLabel) => existingLogs.findLast(row => row[1] === sheetName && row[3] === rowLabel && row[4] === columnLabel);
    // if there are no formulas logged so far for this sheet, add all current formulas
    const range = existingLogs.map(row => row[1]).includes(sheetName) ? e.range : sheet.getDataRange();
    const getLabels_ = (range) => range.getDisplayValues().flat().map(label => label.match(/^(#N\/A!$|#.+!)/) ? '' : label);
    const rowLabels = getLabels_(sheet.getRange(1, sheet.getFrozenColumns() || 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1));
    const columnLabels = getLabels_(sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()));
    const timestamp = new Date();
    const formulas = range.getFormulas();
    const values = range.getDisplayValues();
    const rowStart = range.getRow();
    const columnStart = range.getColumn();
    const result = [];
    for (let row = 0, numRows = formulas.length; row < numRows; row++) {
      for (let column = 0, numColumns = formulas[row].length; column < numColumns; column++) {
        const rowIndex = rowStart + row - 1;
        const rowLabel = rowLabels[rowIndex] || `row ${rowIndex + 1}`;
        const columnIndex = columnStart + column - 1;
        const columnLabel = columnLabels[columnIndex] || `column ${columnIndex}`;
        const newFormula = formulas[row][column];
        const previous = previousLogEntry_(rowLabel, columnLabel);
        const oldFormula = previous?.[5];
        if (!newFormula && !oldFormula) continue;
        const isEditedCell = rowIndex === e.range.rowStart && columnIndex === e.range.columnStart;
        const oldValue = (isEditedCell ? e.oldValue : previous?.[7]) ?? '(unavailable)';
        const cellAddress = columnNumbersToColumnLabels_(columnStart + column) + (rowStart + row);
        result.push([timestamp, sheetName, cellAddress, rowLabel, columnLabel, "'" + newFormula, "'" + (oldFormula || '(unavailable)'), values[row][column], oldValue]);
      }
    }
    if (result.length) appendRows_(logSheet, result);
    if (settings.logSheetAdded) e.range.activate();
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(`${error.message} ${error.stack}`, 'Error in logFormulaChanges_()', 30);
    throw error;
  }
}


/**
* Converts column numbers such as 1, 26, 27 and 18278 into column labels like "A", "Z", "AA" and "ZZZ".
*
* Returns a text string or an array of text strings that matches the dimensions of numbers.
* Supports single values and arrays like [1, 26, 27] or [[1, 2], [13, 14], [27, 28]].
* Returns null for '', null and undefined.
* Returns NaN for non-numbers and numbers less than 1.
*
* @param {Number[][]} numbers A column number or or an array of column numbers to convert to column labels.
* @return {String[][]} Column labels like "A", "Z", "AA" and "ZZZ", or NaN if numbers is not a positive number.
*/
function columnNumbersToColumnLabels_(numbers) {
  // version 1.8, written by --Hyde 2 September 2023
  if (Array.isArray(numbers)) return numbers.map(columnNumbersToColumnLabels_);
  if (numbers === '' || (numbers == null)) return null;
  if (typeof numbers !== 'number' || numbers < 1) return NaN;
  const alphabetStart = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
  const alphabetSize = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0) - alphabetStart + 1;
  let colLabel = '';
  while (numbers > 0) {
    const colNumber = (numbers - 1) % alphabetSize;
    const asciiCode = colNumber + alphabetStart;
    colLabel = String.fromCharCode(asciiCode) + colLabel;
    numbers = (numbers - colNumber - 1) / alphabetSize;
  }
  return colLabel;
}

For that to work, you will need to paste the appendRows_() and getLastRow_() utility functions in your script project as well. You can get those functions from How to append data to a certain column?

Read the answer. "you will need to paste the appendRows_() and getLastRow_() utility functions in your script project as well. You can get those functions from How to append data to a certain column?"

I added appendRows_() function and it works, thanks!

The code in the question looks like an AI hallucination because it includes nonexisting properties for the Edit event object and the documentation style.
Below is a sample script including an on-edit simple trigger that calls one of two functions depending on whether a single cell was edited or multiple cells were edited, i.e., when copy-pasting a range. This also identifies when a single cell of active range and selection has been edited and, in such case, will report the changes of the edited cell.
Each function is documented using JSDoc. Having multiple functions instead of putting all of them in a single function makes it easier to adapt and to make it "unit-testable".
Code.gs
/**
 * The range property of the on edit object includes some properties not documented on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
 *
 * @typedef {Object} Range
 * @extends SpreadsheetApp.Range
 * @property {number} rowStart
 * @property {number} rowEnd
 * @property {number} columnStart
 * @property {number} columnEnd
 */

/**
 * Displays a toast showing a few properties of the edited cell or range
 * @param {Object} e This is the event object.
 * @property {Range} range
 * @property {string|number|boolean|Date} [value]
 * @property {string|number|boolean|Date} [oldValue]
 */
function onEdit(e) {
    const inspection = (
        e.range.rowStart === e.range.rowEnd
        && e.range.columnStart === e.range.columnEnd
    )
        ? inspectCurrentCell(e.range)
        : inspectActiveRange(e.range);
    const message = JSON.stringify(inspection, null, " ")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message);
}

/**
 * Inspects the current cell.
 * @param {Range|SpreadsheetApp.Range} [currentCell]
 * @returns {Object}
 * @property {string} formula
 * @property {string} a1Notation
 * @property {string|number|boolean|Date} value
 */
function inspectCurrentCell(currentCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell()) {
    return {
        formula: currentCell.getFormula(),
        a1Notation: currentCell.getA1Notation(),
        value: currentCell.getValue()
    }
}

/**
 * Inspects the active range.
 * @param {Range|SpreadsheetApp.Range} [activeRange]
 * @returns {Object}
 * @property {string[][]} formulas
 * @property {string} a1Notation
 * @property {(string|number|boolean|Date)[][]} values
 */
function inspectActiveRange(activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()) {
    return {
        formulas: activeRange.getFormulas(),
        a1Notations: activeRange.getA1Notation(),
        values: activeRange.getValues()
    }
}

Note: Google Sheets includes built-in features to track changes: File > Version History and Right-click over a cell to open the contextual menu > Show edit history.
Related

What's the difference between getActiveCell and getCurrentCell in Google Apps Script?

